# when is __cxa_deleted_virtual called

Tags: c++, libstdc++

I try to build a little test case set for avr c++ builds.

There are some "exceptional functions" provided typically from the c++ library. Now I want to write a test program which produces this wrong code which must link to `__cxa_deleted_virtual`.

Can anyone provide a code snippet which results in linking to that function?

I have actually no idea how to produce this "buggy" code.

Comment: I had the same problem with `__cxa_pure_virtual` a while ago, trying to debug the sudden increase in size of my (embedded) binary - despite my efforts to create a minimal "buggy" program, I couldn't have it linked in. I'd love to see C++ gurus' insight on this.

Comment: __cxa_pure_virtual is no problem, simply call a virtual function from the constructor. This is always a failure and results in calling the method.

Comment: ok, I might have overlooked that, thanks. (Anyway I was thinking my comment could add relevant keywords from a search engine standpoint - e.g. if a single resource contained info for "exceptional functions" in general)

Comment: Interesting [llvm does not mention the existance](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/spec.html) of this function

Comment: I tried `struct base { virtual void f() {} };
struct derived : base {  void f() = delete; };
int main()
{
    derived d;
    base& b = d;
    b.f();
}`, but that refuses to compile.  I wonder if you need a compiler which doesn't reject that code?

Answer (score 4):

It's used to fill the vtable slot of a virtual function that has been defined as deleted:

```
struct B { virtual void f() = delete; };
struct D : B { virtual void f() = delete; };
```

(The reason a deleted virtual function is included in the vtable is that [this allows it to be later changed to non-deleted without breaking vtable layout](http://sourcerytools.com/pipermail/cxx-abi-dev/2009-May/002124.html).)

I'm not aware of any way it could actually get called in (relatively sane) C++, since the only thing that can override a function with a deleted definition is another function with a deleted definition ([[class.virtual]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.virtual#16)), and any attempt to call a function with a deleted definition renders the program ill-formed. I suppose you can invoke the specter of ODR violations:

```
// TU 1
struct B { virtual void f() = delete; virtual void g(); };
void B::g() { } // causes vtable to be emitted in this TU

// TU 2
struct B { virtual void f(); virtual void g(); };

void h(B* b) { b->f(); }

int main() {
    B b;
    h(&b);
}
```

Comment: What does ODR stand for?

Comment: How about the calling code using an outdated header that declares the function as not being deleted? This can happen especially easily if the class is provided by a library which is built independently of the code that uses `B`.

Comment: @cmaster ...which is an ODR violation.

Comment: @Eric The [one definition rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR).

Comment: @T.C. Of course, it is an ODR violation. Nevertheless, it is a violation that happens in the wild, leading to such nasty effects as virtual function calls ending up calling the wrong function, etc. (I actually had that once: built a library, forgot to install it, linked code compiled with newer headers against the outdated `.so` file, had a lot of fun debugging the result...). In the case of a deleted function, such an ODR violation might result in `__cxa_deleted_virtual` being called. Of course, if that function ends up being called, it is the build system that is broken and needs fixing.